# Resource for creating Web API like Twitter API or Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, api, programming-languages, twitter

is there any resource for creating Web API like Twitter API or Facebook API.
I want to create a Web API for my website.

thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do is expose a restful service.

To put it simply you'll have urls that return XML or JSON.  See the [stack exchange API docs](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help) and a [sample](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/api-hello-world-code).

You can then create wrappers around this service in as many languages as you like. See the [twitter API overview](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/api_overview), its a REST service, and languages wrap this up nicely. (Like [Linq2Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) for example)

Now you haven't mentioned the language you are using to write your web app, but if you're with **.NET** then look into [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106) and [OData](http://www.odata.org/) which can expose, data entities from a database (among other things) over a RESTful service. See http://www.odataprimer.com/ for examples.

Also See [REST on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) & [How I explained REST to my wife](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife)

For authorization look into [OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth) and http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ if you're with .NET

Note: Facebook initially had REST-API but I **think** the complexity of their platform got them to change their API.